# PHP After extending a class what name do I use

Tags: php, phpmailer, extend

I have extended PHPMailer so I can save the mail to the sent folder.
I used:

```
class Mailer extends PHPMailer {
```

Can I still use:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
```

or should I use:

```
$mail = new Mailer;
```

Comment: If you want to use your extended class you have to use the new name.

Comment: You have to use the class that is extending the parent class. You'll have to use `$mail = new Mailer;`

Comment: If you execute `$mail = new PHPMailer;` its load PHPMailer class only. If you call `$mail = new Mailer;` then its calls Mailer+PHPMailer classes

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555090/php-how-to-use-parent-class-object-variables-in-extended-classes

Comment: @AbdullaNilam how so? That question is about extended classes accessing parents' variables.

Comment: Read [the PHP docs on this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php).

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes I know. that's why I've added that as a comment. instead of **single handly close** this

Answer (score 2):

You should use the new name. When you extend a class it doesn't change the class you are extending, it essentially copies that class to your new class and allows you to add to it.

```
$mail = new Mailer();
```

I would recommend looking up basic OOP for PHP as this will be described. From a quick google search [this came up](https://github.com/marcelgsantos/learning-oop-in-php) and looks good.

As pointed out by @Synchro you should check out the [PHP docs for inheritance](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php) before any other guides.

Comment: First port of call should always be [the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php)

Comment: Thank you, it was just that it still let me use the original class.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.

Do you use namespaces, `use` statement and autoloading? If you didn't you obviously should use new class name, but if you do, you could use aliases like:

```
use Mailer as PHPMailer;
$mail = new PHPMailer;
```

and still use old name